# How to retrieve events that has been changed in EKEventStoreChanged notification

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, ekevent, ekeventkit

I have listened for the notification and whenever there is a modification or change, I am synchronising all the events to the local db. But the problem I have is to know whether I can retrieve only the modified events. This is the EKStoreChanged notification's Userinfo,

```
     "x-apple-eventkit:///Event/p1003",
     "x-apple-eventkit:///Location/p60",
     "x-apple-eventkit:///Location/p61",
     "x-apple-eventkit:///Location/p59",
     "x-apple-eventkit:///Event/p1004",
     "x-apple-eventkit:///Event/p1005"
```

Is it possible to know which event has been changed, or whether it has been deleted?

Answer (score 0):

From apple's documentation:

> Posted whenever changes are made to the Calendar database, including
>   adding, removing, and changing events or reminders. **Individual changes
>   are not described**.

So, you need to fetch each entry to known wether it has changed or not.